# Alter column to make it a derived column

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns

I'm learning PostgreSQL and I'm wondering is it possible to add a derived column to a table then ALTER it on a another line, I've tried different ways but I can't find the correct Syntax for it.

For some reason its seems as if the exercise wants it on two lines, but I can only do it on one at the moment.

```
-- 1) Add an attribute Taxes to table Payment
ALTER TABLE Payment
ADD Taxes real;

-- 2) Set the derived attribute taxes as 12% of PaySlip
ALTER TABLE Payment
ALTER COLUMN Taxes AS (0.12*Payment.PaySlip);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`Generated Columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)

If this column exists in your table, we might need to drop it before creating it.

Due to the document might not support [`ALTER COLUMN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) with `GENERATED`

> ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name ADD GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY [ ( sequence_options ) ]

```
ALTER TABLE Payment DROP COLUMN Taxes;

ALTER TABLE Payment
ADD Taxes  [type of Taxes]  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (0.12 * PaySlip) stored;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4eac48c6fc0accc2aa3e20638993191b)